# Windows 10 Test Mode Enabled but no Watermark

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to load an unsigned driver on Windows 10 (Pro for Workstations). To do this, I need to first enable the Test mode.

I am running the following command from command line in administrator mode:

```
bcdedit.exe /set testsigning on
```

It says the operation completed successfully. However, I do not know how to confirm whether I am indeed in Test Mode or not?

The test mode watermark does not display at the bottom right of the Desktop as shown below:

[image]

My driver still does not load. So, I am trying to understand if there is some other issue or it's due to the test mode not being enabled successfully.

Is there a command which can be used to confirm whether the test mode is enabled or disabled?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to select that particular boot option, as you are booting your system, in order to allow unsigned drivers.

Comment: How do I do that? Could you elaborate?